# r - Unexpected '=' while using group_by and mutate to add a new column based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, group-by, mean, dplyr

I want to group my `dataset` according to 2 columns (`A`, `B`), and then calculate the means of a 3rd column (`C`) based on those sub-groups.

Here is my code:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  mutate(data$my_new_column = mean(C))
```

I get an error stating that there is an unexpected '=' in "group_by(A, B) %>%
mutate(data$my_new_column ="

Any idea? Thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are creating a new column, just remove `data$`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  mutate(my_new_column = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I also had to add `data <- data %>%`